# React testing library id instead of data-testid?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, testing, automated-tests

Would be any difference if I used HTML `id` attribute instead of data attributes like `data-testid`?

Reference for the use of `data-testid` in testing:

https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are at least two reasons to differentiate testing `id`s and regular ones. If both of them are not concerned for you (and the people who will use and maintain the project), then you will feel no difference.

1. **Components reuse**

React Components reuse is one of the core concepts of the framework. And in general, components can appear several times in one page/view. This easily leads to `id`s duplication, which in turn has the potential to break the logic of further processing of the page. Nobody loves duplicated id.

2. **Cleaning the code for production**

It's straightforward to employ any method of getting rid of `data-testid` attribute before publishing your package. But it's hard to be sure you don't clear anything other developers rely on when you keep your testing ids in the regular `id` field.

Comment: _This easily leads to ids duplication_ 
then it means the same problem for data-testid

Comment: You're right, but this is how test ids protect you. While they're used only for testing purposes as intended -- only tests could be broken this way, and it won't introduce any worries to production logic.

Comment: @aldokkani no, ids do break your app when processing the page, on the other hand data-testid's don't, even if repeated, you'll only get repeated instances of the elements when using getByTestId or query selection, and even then doable, but that's about it

Answer (score 31):

On the surface, I don't see any technical difference.

But in terms of readability, `data-testid` may notice other developers that this is used for test case specifically, while `id` is may be in terms of styling.

Also `id` or `class` selectors can be changed more often if implementation changes.

Reference:

[Making your UI tests resilient to change](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/making-your-ui-tests-resilient-to-change)